# Decision tree- is it overfitting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I am building a tree classifier and I would like to check and fix the possible overfitting. 
These are the calcuations:

```
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3,min_samples_split=3,min_samples_leaf=1, random_state=0)
dtc_fit = dtc.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Accuracy using Decision Tree:" ,round(score, 1), "%")

('Accuracy using Decision Tree:', 92.2, '%')


scores = cross_val_score(dtc_fit, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
Accuracy: 0.91 (+/- 0.10)
```

What are the possible values I could fix to get a better result or perhaps these are already fine?

Thank you for the help, I am a beginner therefore unsure of the outcome.

Comment: what's the dataset size? you may want to increase the value of `min_samples_leaf`

Comment: @Ereli the size of the dataset is 368,it is not a big dataset...

Comment: it's too small IMO to have real validity.

Comment: This question is not answerable because it depends highly on what the problem and the data is.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly if it is overfitting or not, but you can give [gridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) a try for the following reasons

- It will split your datasets into multiple combinations of different splits, hence you will get to know if the decision tree is overfitting on your training set or not (Although this might not neccessary be a valid way of knowing)
- You can add various parameters by making a dictionary of various parameters and the values that they can have like this

  ```
  from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

  parameters_dict = {"max_depth": [2,5,6,10], "min_samples_split" : [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], "min_samples_leaf" = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], "criterion": ["gini","entropy"]}

  dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state= 0)

  grid_obj = GridSearchCV(estimator=dtc,param_grid=parameters_dict, cv=10)

  grid_obj.fit(X_train,y_train)

  #Extract the best classifier
  best_clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_
  ```
- Also you can try [Recursive Feature Elimination with CV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn-feature-selection-rfecv) to find the best features. (This is an optional thing to do btw)
- You can check other metrics like precision, recall, f1-score, etc. to get an idea if your decision tree is not overfitting the data (or is giving importance to one class over the others)
- Also, as a side note just be sure that your data does not suffer from class imbalance problem.

This is not an exhaustive list and not necessarily the best ways to check overfitting but you can give it a try.